# How do I resolve keeping a character tied to a rope from falling?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, equipment, falling

I have run into this a lot recently. PCs walking over a bridge or a log or whatever over a chasm will tie a rope around one of the characters and the rest will hold the end of the rope as he crosses, thus catching him if he falls.

Is it just a strength check to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn’t really spelled out under the rules, you just have to combine checks as you see fit as DM. You could ask for Use Rope to check the strength of the knot. Ropes themselves have stats for how much weight they can hold. If the chasm is particularly wide, swinging into the wall beneath those holding the rope could still hurt.

But frankly, none of that really seems worth the time. I probably wouldn’t even bother with the Strength check, unless they were really pushing their luck.

Comment: Further believe a strength check shouldn't be needed by participants if they can carry the weight of the person (that's tablized in the PH).

Comment: @joedragons But a falling shock's “weight” can be *far* greater than the resting weight of an object/person, so that wouldn't make much sense. It's not like the falling person is being gently picked up.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is "shock" a written rule or are you imposing it?

Comment: @joedragons He’s talking about reality. He’s kind of misusing the word “weight” from a technical, physics standpoint (*weight* is typically defined as the *force* that an object exerts due to the force of gravity acting on it: Newton’s equal and opposite reaction to gravity—and that doesn’t change due to motion), but it’s definitely a real thing. Something that could support a given weight if gently lifting can easily snap if the same weight is just dropped on it.

Comment: Yeah, @KRyan has the right of it. (Those scare quotes are there for that weight/mass/force wrinkle. Being schooled in physics in metric, the distinction between mass and weight was drilled into us. "Weight" is still not quite right here because a shock isn't a resting force, but I figured scared-quoted "weight" is more approachable than physics jargon…)

Comment: @joedragons It's just what's happening when someone falls, and "what's happening" is what a DM is considering when deciding what *ad hoc* rolls to call for. Looking at carry weight is what you suggested, and that's one way to inform such a DM call, but it's not actually much related to what "falling" means when considering "what's happening?" (Note that using carry weight is also not a rule. Our judgements are each equally unsupported by any rule dictating that's how to handle this.)

Comment: (For what it’s worth, @SevenSidedDie, in my experience physics is *always* taught in metric; I have only ever studied the subject in America and yet it’s still done in metric. The only time we ever saw American customary measures was in engineering classes, and even then it was an aberration and students were really annoyed at the professor for doing it. But I’m not sure how recently the switch to metric for physics classes was.)

Answer (score 0):

there's a table in the PHB core for how much weight each strength can lift. Add them all together and compare that total to the same chart. Use that strength table for the Strength check. If they are ready, DC 10, if they aren't expecting him to fall or are distracted, DC 15+.

for added excitement, you can do the checks sequentially, so if the first person is distracted, you lose their weight bonus, but move on to the next character, and so on until the last person's chance to save the character slips through their fingers.